# How do I use Smalltalk's built in Parser or Compiler to parse my own messages with optional parameters?

Tags: smalltalk, optional-parameters

I'm trying to create a live-coding environment in Smalltalk. The objects I'm using have long complex methods with many parameters for creating new instances. I want to be able to write a very short "command" that just specifies the parameters I'm interested in and provides default values for all the other parameters.

For instance instead of writing something like:

```
Polyhedron shape: #cube size: 1 rotationSpeed: 5 rotationDirection: 0.707 color: red texture: false
```

In my live coding environment I want to write:

```
poly shape: #cube
```

Some of the arguments could be complex and contain their own messages like:

```
poly shape: #cube rotationSpeed: ((pot1 max: 0) min: speedLimit)
```

So rather than just trying to parse the live coding string myself I thought it would be easier if I could use Smalltalk's built in parser or compiler to decode the string and call `Polyhedron` with the full creation message including default values.

How would I do that?

I've got as far as getting an array of tokens out of the parser but that doesn't identify message parameters and arguments. Before I tried to implement argument parsing myself I figured there's likely to be something in Smalltalk that could give me a list of message parameters and arguments?

Comment: It's not clear to me yet why the complexity is needed. If `pot1` is an object that accepts messages `min:` and `max:` then when you call `poly shape: #cube rotationSpeed: ((pot1 max: 0) min: speedLimit)`, then Smalltalk will evaluate `((pot1 max: 0) min: speedLimit)` before it is passed in as a selector argument.

Comment: I want to write my own abbreviated string representation which I'll evaluate. In this example "poly shape: #cube". That string is the abbreviated form of "Polyhedron shape: #cube rotationSpeed:....". My question is when I try and process and evaluate my abbreviated string is there a way I can make use of the Compiler so I get message parsing for free? You're right if I pass "((pot1 max: 0) min: speedLimit)" as the argument for the rotationSpeed: parameter Smalltalk will do the right thing and evaluate that. But is there an easy way for me to extract that argument from my string?

Comment: Ok thanks for clarifying. In your example you didn't write it as a string.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't look like you have to tweak the compiler. To provide default values simply have your objects be born with them. How? In the initialize method:

```
Polyhedron >> initialize
   super initialize.
   shape := #triangle.
   size := 1.
   rotationSpeed := 5.
   rotationDirection := 0.707.
   color: Color red texture: false
```

The `#initialize` message is sent when you send `Polyhedron new`. Thus, if you want to change the shape, you only need to send

```
Polyhedron new shape: #cube
```

Note by the way that it is usually a good idea to send `super initialize` so to give superclasses a chance to perform their initialization routines.

Note also that Polyhedra is the plural of Polyhedron, and class names are usually in singular.

---

**Addendum**

---

In case you cannot edit the class `Polyhedron`, you can still reference it and therefore send messages to it. In particular, you can create new instance creation methods, shorter than the ones you already have. Here is how to do this:

```
   Polyedron compile: 'shape: aSymbol
   ^self
     shape: aSymbol
     size: 1
     rotationSpeed: 5
     rotationDirection: 0.707
     color: Color rd texture: false'
```

Note that the argument of `#compile:` is the source code of the method you want to add. By using this new method you will be able to just say

```
Polyedron shape: #cube
```

to get what you wanted.

Comment: Thank you, I learnt a lot from your answer. Unfortunately it won't work in this case. I'm using a library of objects I can't edit. Also I made a mistake in my question (I've now corrected). The objects don't use "new", instead they have a long complex creation method with all their parameters and seem to then be immutable.  This is why I was thinking I'd need to parse my abbreviated string representation, add in the default values, and make the large creation message.

Comment: @AlanMJackson Thanks for the clarification. Please read the **Addendum** to my former answer.